# Simple Python 3 email/password storage

Tags: python

This would probably be my first code and I'm so happy that I applied the knowledge I obtained from watching youtube videos and It does make sense to me why and how they work!

However, I want to make the program below a little more complex. Currently the program asks the user to make a choice, and then to enter a related username or email. E.g. if the choice was `1`, it'd ask for the "Main Email", and then it prints the password for that email/user account.

But I have a problem: I don't know how to check if the email/username is correct. The program should only print the password if a correct email is provided. And I'd also like it to not require the numerical choice, but only ask for the email, and from that decide what password is the email for.

I was thinking of doing `if`-`else` statements but I can only do them with integers and floats? Or else I'm just not researching enough, so here I am asking first.

```
print ("Select the password you would wanna know from the email")
print ("1. Main Email")
print ("2. Your steam account steam guard")

while True:
    choice = input ("Enter your choice (1/2/): ")

    if choice in ("1",):
        email1 = input("Enter your password in your main email: ")
        
    if choice in ("2"):
        email2 = input("Enter your steamguard: ")

    if choice == "1":
        print( "The password is *myemailpassword*")
    if choice == "2":
        print ("Your steam guard password is *steamguardpassword*")
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your problem. Can't you do `if email1 == "me@post.com"` ? You can nested one `if/else` in another `if/else`

Comment: I don't understand why you use `if choice in ("1",):` And why you use later `if choice == "1":`. It is almost the same.

Comment: Because I'm new to this thing but I really appreciate you for that feedback!

Answer (score 1):

> I was thinking of doing if else statements but I can only do them with integers and floats?

Not at all. If statements actually take anything that is truthy or falsy, not only ints nor floats, and you can use the comparison operator `==` to compare two strings, the result being `True` if they are equal in value, and otherwise `False`.

In your code, you're already using the `in` operator to work with tuples, so even in your own code you don't believe the statement about `if` working only on integers and floats! The `in` operator works - in your case - on a (string, list) pair of arguments, and the `==` operator works - in your case - on a (string, string) pair.

**You're not using integers nor floats *anywhere* in your code!**
`"1"` is *not* an integer. It's a string that contains a decimal numeral. Thus, `"1" + "2"` results in `"12"`, not `3`, and `"1" + 2` throws *TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str*. With actual integers, `1 + 2` is `3` (note: no quotes!).

What you perhaps want can be written as:

```
passwords = {
  "email1@example.com": ["email password", "password1"],
  "email2@example.com": ["steamguard password", "password2"]
}

print("Empty input ends the program.")
while True:
  choice = input("Enter email or username: ").strip()
  if not choice:
    break
  if choice in passwords:
    what, password = passwords[choice]
    print("Your", what, "is", password)
  else:
    print("Invalid entry. Try again.")
print("Goodbye.")
```

I've used a dictionary to hold the data - this is called data-driven design. It helps decouple the code from the data it operates on. It's easy to think of the passwords as a "table" or "dictionary" where you look things up!

The `string.strip()` method removes any leading and trailing whitespace in the string.

The `not` operator treats its argument as either falsy or truthy. In Python, many non-boolean expressions can be falsy - e.g. the integer `0`, the boolean `False`, or an empty string `""`. Thus, `not choice` means "when choice is falsy", or, here: "when choice is empty".

The "double" assignment `what, password = ...` is a destructuring assignment: it takes whatever's on the right side of `=`, breaks it up into two parts, and assigns the first part to `what`, and the second part to `password`. That way the `["what", "password"]` list looked up in the dictionary has its structure removed, and its contents extracted into named variables.

Comment: Hello! thank you for this explanation! Although I really am new at coding. It somehow enlightened me on what to do! I really appreciate you kind sir!